# Is there a way to alter many tables to add default values to a common column name?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a set of 45 tables which carry a common column {`variety`}.
The need is to set all such columns with a default value {`comedy`}.

The `ALTER TABLE (SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME) MODIFY(VARIETY DEFAULT 'COMEDY')`

Will get it done, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a sql script in Oracle 11g that will change all tables within the schema which have a common coloumn name to the common default value.

Comment: You can loop over user_tables and user_columns to build an execute immediate statement and run it on the fly whether there's the column you need in the table. If the schema is not the one you're running the query from you'll need the rights on all_tables and all_columns and use these 2 tables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.table_name 
        FROM user_tables t
            INNER JOIN user_tab_columns c ON c.table_name = t.table_name
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE (SCHEMA.' || x.table_name || ') MODIFY(VARIETY DEFAULT ''COMEDY'')';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am getting ORA-06550 'encountered select when expecting one fo the following (-+ case mod <an identifier> etc..  Seems like the first SELECT is not what was expected at that point.........................................

Comment: try with the parenthesis I added (sorry i don't have an environment to try out) Also added the column filter.

Comment: I'd add in "where dropped = 'NO'"

Answer (score 0):

The alter table statement can be written as following,
using alternate quoting mechanism.

```
'alter table ' || x.table_name || q'[ modify (variety default 'COMEDY')]'
```